# TypeORM - MYSQL - @OneToOne annotation

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, typeorm

I've got two tables in my MySQL database:

### 1 Table Channel:

```
CREATE TABLE `channel` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `youtubeId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `language` int NOT NULL,
  `lastUpdatedDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `createdDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_LANGUAGE` (`language`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_LANGUAGE` FOREIGN KEY (`language`) REFERENCES `language` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

And Entity in TypeOrm looks like:

```
@Entity()
export class Channel {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  youtubeId: string;

  @OneToOne((type) => Language)
  @Column()
  language: Language;

  @Column()
  lastUpdatedDate: Date;

  @Column()
  createdDate: Date;
}
```

### 2 Table Language

```
CREATE TABLE `language` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

And Entity in TypeORM looks like:

```
@Entity()
export class Language {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  code: string;
}
```

### ERROR:

Problem is that once I start my nodejs server I get an error:

> DataTypeNotSupportedError: Data type "Language" in "Channel.language"
>   is not supported by "mysql" database.

I'm not really great in databases and I try to learn TypeORM so currnetly I'm in situation when I don't know if I messed up something in TypeORM or in my database. Any advise which can lead me right way is more then welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @JoinColumn() instead of @Column()

The @JoinColumn() will create a foreign key language_id to the Channel Table

```
@Entity()
export class Channel {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  youtubeId: string;

  @OneToOne((type) => Language)
  @JoinColumn()
  language: Language;

  @Column()
  lastUpdatedDate: Date;

  @Column()
  createdDate: Date;
}
```